# Append data to new cell arrays using Token

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, append, cells

I have a problem I couldnt solve it. I have a set of data present in lines (generally text that are organized in number of sentences)

Example of my text in sentence:

```
1. Hello, world, It, is, beautiful, to, see, you, all
2. ,Wishing, you, happy, day, ahead
```

I am using the strtok

```
    [token remain] = strtok(remain, ', ');

%             token = strtrim(token);
            CellArray {NumberOFCells} = token(1:end) ;  
            NumberOFCells= NumberOFCells+1;
```

I am using the CellArray to store the Token into the cells however what my code does is it takes the first sentences and put into cells and once it iterates to the second sentence  and it deletes the pre-assigned cells thus it replaces it with token of the second sentences.

Expected Output

```
  [ nxn ] [ nxn    ] [  ] [ ]   [       ]   [     ] [   ] [  ]  [       ] ...... 
    'Hello' 'world' 'It' 'is' 'beautiful' 'to' see' 'you' 'all' 'Wishing' 'you' 'happy' 'day' 'ahead'
```

The question is how can I append the second sentence strings to the cells without clearing the pre-filled cells.

Thank you and looking forward to meet experts matlab programmer

My Code .. Ignore commented lines... Retrieved is basically in this form.

```
[Index,Retrieved] = system(['wn ' keyword   type  ]);

    Retrieved;
    arrowSymbol = ' => ';
    CommaSymbol= ', '
    NumberOfSense= 'Sense '; 

    % let's look for the lines with '=> ' only?
     senses = regexp(Retrieved, [arrowSymbol '[\w, ]*\n '], 'match');
     SplitIntoCell = regexp(senses, [CommaSymbol '[\w, ]*\n'], 'match');

   % now, we take out the '=> ' symbol
    for i = 1:size(senses, 2)

        senses{i} = senses{i}(size(arrowSymbol,2):end);
        SplitIntoCell{i}= SplitIntoCell{i}(size(CommaSymbol,2): end);
%         SeperateCells= senses ([1:2 ; end-1:end]);
%         SplitCellContentIntoSingleRows{i}= strtok (SeperateCells, ['\n' ])
        numberCommas = size(regexp(senses{i}, CommaSymbol), 2);

        remain = senses{i};
        RestWord= SplitIntoCell{i};
        NumberOFCells=1;
        for j = 2:numberCommas + 1 + 1 % 1 for a word after last comma and 1 because starts at index 2

%             RemoveCellComma= regexp (Conversion,',');

%            CellArray = [CellArray strsplit(remain, ', ')];
%            [str,~] = regexp(remain,'[^, \t]+', 'match', 'split');
%            CellArray = [CellArray str];

%              [token remain] = strtok(remain, ', ');
%              token = strtrim(token);
%              CellArray {NumberOFCells} = token(1:end) ;  
%              
% %              CellArray =[CellArray strsplit(remain, ', ')]
%              [str, ~]= regexp(remain,'[^, \t]+', 'match', 'split');
%              CellArray = [CellArray str];
%              NumberOFCells= NumberOFCells+1;

            [token remain] = strtok(remain, ', ');
            token = strtrim(token);
            CellArray {NumberOFCells} = token;   
            NumberOFCells= NumberOFCells+1;
```

Retrieved=

```
cat, true cat
       => feline, felid
           => carnivore
               => placental, placental mammal, eutherian, eutherian mammal
                   => mammal, mammalian
                       => vertebrate, craniate
                           => chordate
                               => animal, animate being, beast, brute, creature, fauna
                                   => organism, being
                                       => living thing, animate thing
                                           => object, physical object
                                               => physical entity
                                                   => entity
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve (_i.e_ the desired final result)?

Comment: @EitanT I have updated my question. In the expected output. I want to store the two sentences in cells instead of store the first one and then erases it and replace it with a new one

Comment: So, in simple words, you want to divide all your sentences into words and store all the words in one cell array? What does the `[nxn]` mean? How are your original sentences stored?

Comment: Yes correct, divide all the sentences into words and store every single word in a cell array NOT all the words in once cell array

Comment: So you'll end up with a cell array of cell arrays, right?

Comment: Your question is poorly phrased and you do not know what you want. Same as with your previous one. You're throwing in some excerpts of code, stir them a bit with unclear input formatted according to your imagination and you pretend the experts? If you ever watched the [Mothman Prophecies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0265349/), then how is a God to talk to us if we ourselves cannot convey our ideas to ants? The experts are here, provide a clear example of valid MATLAB input (copy-paste-executable in the cmd window) and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but reading it (and other comments) a couple of times, I think I understand what you're asking.

Eitan T is correct about using regexp for this, and when it comes to cell arrays, be careful of the difference in indexing/concatenation with [] and {}: see [Combining Cell Arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-cell-arrays.html). Assuming your using a loop to go through each sentence, you can do something like:

```
CellArray = [CellArray strsplit(next_sentence, ', ')];
```

Using [regexp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) (or it's case-insensitive alternative [regexpi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html)), try adding `'split'` as another one of the function options, for example:

```
[str,~] = regexp(next_sentence,'[^, \t]+', 'match', 'split');
CellArray = [CellArray str];
```

Comment: CellArray = [CellArray strsplit(next_sentence, ', ')];  Can you explain to me what is CellArray. in the []. Are you suggesting that I dont need to use strtoke ? In my case the next sentence is meant the next cell that contain a next sentence

Can you explain

Comment: It's the cell array of your tokens. For example, if CellArray = {'cat','dog'} initially, and I do `CellArray = [CellArray 'horse']`, where 'horse' is the output of the `strsplit` function, CellArray will now be {'cat','dog','horse'}. Read the "Combining Cell Arrays" I linked to above.

Comment: Yeah but here what I got from executing the code above Undefined function 'strsplit' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: Can you edit your question above with more of your verbatim MATLAB code? Try the regexp answer also, but it's hard to help you troubleshoot with so little code.